# How to replace a Nth occurrence in a string (PHP)

Tags: php, algorithm

Say, there is an array:

```
array:4 [
  0 => "{__}"
  1 => "{one|two|three}"
  2 => "{__}"
  3 => "{red|green|blue}"
]
```

and text:

```
> Lorem {__} dolor sit amet, consectetur {one|two|three} elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore {__} aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo {one|two|three}. Duis {red|green|blue} irure
> dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
> nulla pariatur.
```

How to replace all **{__}** to `<input type="text" name="text[n]" />` *(n - number of entry)* and all **{a|b|c|...|N}** to

```
<select name="list[n]">
  <option value="1">a</option>
  <option value="2">b</option>
  <option value="3">c</option>
  <option value="4">...</option>
  <option value="N">N</option>
</select>
```

*(n - number of entry)*

Comment: please show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Your Algo should be something like

1- read string from input

2- $Step2arr = break to arrays using '{__}'

3- run foreach for array that we got from step one

```
$newstr = '' ;

foreach($Step2arr as $key=>$val){
    if( count($Step2arr) - 1 < $key )
    $newstr  = $newstr.$val.'<input type="text" name="text['.$key.']" /> ' ; 
}
```

4- Now new string have something $newstr string like "Lorem

Now you could repeat the same process for second {a|b|c} string also